# Does the 3-Clause BSD license allow this

Tags: licensing, bsd

Neither a native english speaker nor a law expert.

I'm making a development tool, which allows user to export and redistribute standalone binary from the tool. The exported binary contains my tool's name and logo.

In the license https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause, I understand clearly what the former two clauses mean, but for the third:

"3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission."

Does it conflict to that the software encourages users to keep and show my tool's name and logo in their redistribution?

Comment: The clause is more or less superflous, but reminds other people to not abuse your name to advertise *modified* versions of the software with which you might not want to be affiliated, e.g. if the modification introduces malware :) E.g. if I write a package manager other people can mention that their *modified* version is “based on amon's package manger” (that's just factual) but can't advertise their version as “amon's original package manager” or “amon thinks this package manager is best”.

Comment: @amon that pretty much is an answer

Comment: @amon Fair clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any "endorsement" or "promotion" happening here.